# Loading Image from Excel and Exporting Image Missing Apache POI

Tags: java, excel, spring, apache-poi

I'm loading an excel document using

```
Resource resource = resourceLoader.getResource("pathhere");
File file = resource.getFile();
FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fileInputStream);
```

I'm then writing it using

```
ByteArrayOutputStream bios = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
workbook.write(bios);
byte[] byteArray = bios.toByteArray();
InputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(byteArray);
```

I then write this to an sftp input stream to a fileshare. The excel doc that is loaded has a image, but the output file does not. All other data is there besides the images. **Why are my images not displaying in the output excel file**?

I'm using apache poi 4.1.0 and see no exceptions in the console.

Comment: Having only your provided code pieces, there cannot be a reason for the described issue if the pictures are included in the `Excel` workbook gotten from the resource file. After `workbook.write(bios);` the `bios` contains the full `workbook` inclusive all included pictures. Only reason can be that the pictures are not included but linked and the system which opens the new created file is not able following the links.

Comment: @AxelRichter Thanks for the response. If I am to copy and paste a picture into an excel document, would this be a linked picture? Shouldn't poi pick this up?

Comment: The default is to include pictures embedded into the workbook. So one needs to explicit insert a linked picture if you don't want an embedded one. And `apache poi` is picking this up exactly as it is in the workbook.

Comment: @AxelRichter Okay i'm going to check the workbook after it's loaded with poi to see if I can find the image to make sure it's loaded properly. I have no other code really to add other than the sftp export which I proved to work correctly with everything but the image part. Is it possible spring security is preventing the loading of an image?